# Android CameraX mirror video recording

Tags: android, android-camerax

I want to be able to mirror video recordings coming from the front camera. Is there a way to be able to flip the recording horizontally just like you can for an ImageCapture's metadata?

Answer (score 0):

Currently (Version 1.2.0-beta01) this feature is not available for video using CameraX.

If you really need to mirror video recording, You can use [CameraView](https://1.2.0-beta01https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) - `takeVideoSnapshot()`.